# How to get the objects in the Thread?

Tags: java, stack-overflow, alfresco, stack-trace, business-process-management

I have a problem with `Activitiy 5.22.0.` Sometimes, my business process throws

> StackOverFlowError (ExecutionEntity.perfomOperation())

The error occurs 1 time / 50 times. To solve this problem, I need to get the created objects in the Thread at this moment? How can I do it? I use Java 8.

Comment: Why do you need to get the objects?

Answer (score 1):

Java does not store objects on the stack. A stack overflow in Java is almost always caused by a too deep recursion. Just calling `exception.printStackTrace()` should help to pinpoint the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, Activiti works on recursion.

Comment: Then the problem is Activiti itself. It's bad design to rely on recursion for user-provided data. Just set a breakpoint on `java.lang.StackOverflowError`.